# Tabs won't work in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-tabs

I need to create tabs in a reservation form (3 tabs) that contain text boxes for the user to fill out then submit. I can't seem to get it to work though and I'm not sure why? Did I place the content (the text boxes) in the wrong place?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 //tabs function
 $("#reservation_tabs").tabs();
 
 var emailPattern = /\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b/;
  
 // add a span element after each text box
 $(":text").after("<span class='error'>*</span>");
 
 // move the focus to the first text box
 $("#arrival_date").focus();
 
 // the handler for the submit event of the form
 // executed when the submit button is clicked
 $("#reservation_form").submit(
  function(event) {
   var isValid = true;
   
   // validate the requested arrival date
   if ($("#arrival_date").val() == "") {
    $("#arrival_date").next().text("This field is required.");
    isValid = false;
   } else {
    $("#arrival_date").next().text("");    
   }
   
   // validate the number of nights
   if ($("#nights").val() == "") {
    $("#nights").next().text("This field is required.");
    isValid = false;
   } else if (isNaN($("#nights").val())) {
    $("#nights").next().text("This field must be numeric.");
    isValid = false;
   } else {
    $("#nights").next().text("");
   }  

   // validate the name entry
   var name = $("#name").val().trim();
   if (name == "") {
    $("#name").next().text("This field is required.");
    isValid = false;
   } 
   else {
    $("#name").val(name);
    $("#name").next().text("");
   }
      
   // validate the email entry with a regular expression
   var email = $("#email").val();
   if (email == "") { 
    $("#email").next().text("This field is required.");
    isValid = false;
   } else if ( !emailPattern.test(email) ) {
    $("#email").next().text("Must be a valid email address.");
    isValid = false;
   } else {
    $("#email").next().text("");
   } 
   
   // validate the phone number
   if ($("#phone").val() == "") { 
    $("#phone").next().text("This field is required.");
    isValid = false; 
   } else {
    $("#phone").next().text("");
   }
   
   // prevent the submission of the form if any entries are invalid 
   if (isValid == false) {
    event.preventDefault();    
   }
  } // end function
 ); // end submit
}); // end ready
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 87.5%;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
legend {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: .8em;
}
label {
 float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
input, select {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
input {
    width: 14em; 
}
input.left {
 width: 1em;
 padding-left: 0;
}
fieldset {
 border: none;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-top: 1em;
 padding: 0;
}
input.last {
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}
#adults, #children {
 width: 35px;
}
#smoking {
 width: 1em;
 margin-left: 0;
}
#policies {
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 15em;
}
#submit {
 width: 10em;
}
#dialog p {
 font-size: 85%;
}
.error {
 float: none;
 color: red;
 font-size: 85%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Reservation request</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="reservation.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body>
 <h1>Reservation Request</h1>
 <form action="response.html" method="get"
     name="reservation_form" id="reservation_form">
  
  <div id="reservation_tabs">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#general_information">General Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#preferences">Preferences</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact_information">Contact Information</a></li>
   </ul>
   
  
         
   <div id="general_information">
    <label for="arrival_date">Arrival date:</label>
    <input type="text" name="arrival_date" id="arrival_date" autofocus><br>
    <label for="nights">Nights:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nights" id="nights"><br>
    <label>Adults:</label>
    <select name="adults" id="adults">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>                              
    </select><br>
    <label>Children:</label>
    <select name="children" id="children">
     <option value="0">0</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>                              
    </select><br>   
   </div>
  
  
         
   <div id="preferences">
    <label>Room type:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="room" id="standard" class="left" checked>Standard&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;          
    <input type="radio" name="room" id="business" class="left">Business&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="room" id="suite" class="left last">Suite<br>
    <label>Bed type:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="bed" id="king" class="left" checked>King&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="bed" id="double" class="left last">Double Double<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="smoking" id="smoking">Smoking<br>
   </div>
  
      
   <div id="contact_information">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
    <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="999-999-9999"><br>
   </div>
  </div>
  
     <fieldset>
      <input type="button" id="policies" value="View Cancellation Policies">
   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Request">
   <div id="dialog" title="Cancellation Policies" style="display: none;">
    <p>Notification of cancellation or arrival date change must be 
    received more than three days (72 hours) prior to the confirmed arrival date for the 
    reservation deposit to be refundable. Email notification is acceptable, and a cancellation
    confirmation will be sent to you. Failure to check-in on the scheduled arrival date 
    will result in the cancellation of the reservation including any remaining nights, 
    and the reservation deposit shall be forfeited.</p>
   </div><br>      
     </fieldset>

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to include the tabs jquery script or cdns links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabs are part of the jQuery UI https://jqueryui.com/tabs/ lib (it's different file than the jQuery itself, so you need them both) which you haven't referenced. (cdns [here](https://code.jquery.com/ui/))

Comment: How do I reference?

Comment: After the jQuery script, put this: <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>